# Using Time Zones in Postman

Tags: postman

I need to use `var timezone = moment.utc(dateTime).tz(time_zone,"UTC").format();` and added this `const moment = require('moment-timezone');` but getting error as `Cannot find module 'moment-timezone'`. Can any one please help me.

Comment: Do you have moment-timezone installed on your system?

Answer (score 0):

```
pm.sendRequest("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.33/moment-timezone-with-data-2012-2022.js", (err, res) => {
    pm.sendRequest("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.js", (err2, res2) => {



        (new Function(res2.text()))();
        (new Function(res.text()))();

        console.log(moment.utc().tz("America/Los_Angeles","UTC").format())
    })
})
```

you can use cdn equivalent of moment-timezone , you have to initialize moment first to use.

Just copy paste this and add to your pre or test scripts

## Update:

The above script works only once as it is messing up global variables. so use below code instead :

```
let a = (res) => new Function(pm.variables.get(res))
pm.sendRequest("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.33/moment-timezone-with-data-2012-2022.min.js", (err, res) => {
    pm.sendRequest("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js", (err2, res2) => {

        pm.environment.set("res2", res2.text());
        pm.environment.set("res", res.text());

        eval(pm.environment.get("res2"));
        eval(pm.environment.get("res"));


        console.log(this.moment.utc().tz("America/Los_Angeles", "UTC").format())


    })
})
```

### Now you can reuse the code in any place as :

```
eval(pm.environment.get("res2"));
eval(pm.environment.get("res"));


console.log(this.moment.utc().tz("America/Los_Angeles", "UTC").format())
```